# Blade auth()->user() Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using spatie permissions package: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

The package does not have a directive to check if a user has any permission, though method `hasAnyPermission` does exist.

I'm trying to use the following conditional in blade:

```
@if (auth()->user()->hasAnyPermission(['View Users', 'View Roles']))
```

This is causing a `Trying to get property of non-object` of error.

Why is this happening?

EDIT

I am going to post more of the code in the layout:

```
@if (auth()->guest())
    <!-- Guest Menu -->
    <li {{ (request()->is('login') ? 'class=active' : '') }}><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
    @if (config('lion.allow_registration'))
        <li {{ (request()->is('register') ? 'class=active' : '') }}><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
    @endif
@else
    <!-- Auth Menu -->
    @if (auth()->user()->hasAnyPermission(['View Users', 'View Roles']))
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                Settings <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                @can('View Users')
                    <li {{ (request()->is('users') ? 'class=active' : '') }}><a href="{{ route('users') }}">Users</a></li>
                @endcan
                @can('View Roles')
                    <li {{ (request()->is('roles') ? 'class=active' : '') }}><a href="{{ route('roles') }}">Roles</a></li>
                @endcan
            </ul>
        </li>
    @endif
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
            {{ auth()->user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li {{ (request()->is('profile') ? 'class=active' : '') }}><a href="{{ route('profile') }}">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
@endif
```

This codes works perfectly without the conditional statement `@if (auth()->user()->hasAnyPermission(['View Users', 'View Roles']))`.

Comment: that means that 'auth()' returns 'null'. Try using Auth::user()->has... instead

Comment: You also try following `@if (Auth::guest())<p>A guest</p>@else<p>A user</p>`

Comment: That isn't right because in the same template I am able to use `{{ auth()->user()->name }}` which echoes the users name fine.

Comment: check in the config folder> auth.php file, in the provider array, the 'user model' is pointing to the correct class.

Comment: I updated the OP with more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating a custom blade directive for this:

```
Blade::directive('hasanypermission', function ($permissions) {
    $permissions = explode(',', $permissions);
    $conditional = [];

    foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
        $conditional[] = "Gate::check($permission)";
    }

    return "<?php if (".implode(' || ', $conditional)."): ?>";
});
Blade::directive('endhasanypermission', function () {
    return '<?php endif; ?>';
});
```

How to use it:

```
@hasanypermission('Read Users', 'Read Roles')
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
            Settings <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            @can('Read Users')
                <li {{ (request()->is('users') ? 'class=active' : '') }}><a href="{{ route('users') }}">Users</a></li>
            @endcan
            @can('Read Roles')
                <li {{ (request()->is('roles') ? 'class=active' : '') }}><a href="{{ route('roles') }}">Roles</a></li>
            @endcan
        </ul>
    </li>
@endhasanypermission
```